# Impossible to import pandas ! "Is this due to the latest release?"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

I'm trying to import pandas and I'm facing some issues

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
```

result:

```py
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in <module>
     57 import pandas.core.sorting as sorting
     58 from pandas.io.formats.printing import pprint_thing
---> 59 from pandas.core.ops import _comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY
     60 from pandas.core import strings, accessor
     61 from pandas.core.config import get_option

ImportError: cannot import name 'ops'
```

OR

```py
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following step and restart the jupyter notebook:

```
conda upgrade --all
```

If it is still showing the same error, try downgrading the pandas version:

```
pip install pandas==0.22.0
```

Hope this helps.